# jQuery textcomplete regex match not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm using this [jQuery](http://yuku-t.com/jquery-textcomplete/) plugin(part 3) to autocomplete the text a user writes.

This is the working match regex : `match: /\B@(\w*)$/,`
My problem is I would like it to now show before the person write `@a` or `@b` or so on.

I tried this but it don't work: `match: /\B@(\w{1*,})$/,`

Can someone tell me what will make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex is not valid.

Remove `*` from limiting quantifier

```
match: /\B@(\w{1*,})$/
//              ^
```

Also, `\B` will not work here.

```
match: /@(\w{1,})$/
```

You can also use `+` instead of `{1,}`([Thanks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33256581/jquery-textcomplete-regex-match-not-working-correctly/33256622?noredirect=1#comment54314770_33256622) to [stribizhev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/stribizhev))

```
match: /@(\w+)$/
```

Comment: Wow silly my, thanks alot, will mark this as answer when I can

Comment: maybe posible to catch you fast, If i try to write your name Tushar I have to start with a Big T, is it posible to modify it so it dont care if it's small or big letters?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen `\w` will match alphabets both uppercase and lowercase

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen And if you are referring to `\B` as word boundary, it should be `\b` and not required here

Comment: @Tushar: No, `\b` won't work unless there is something like `word@a`. And why using `{1,}`? Just use `+`. And `{1,}` is not a range, it is a limiting quantifier.